# How do I get the Path to the latest created file in a folder with apple script?

Tags: applescript, filepath

I want to get the path to the last file created in folder test

```
set p to "/Users/palmglow/Documents/googledrive/orders/IFTTT/test"
set a to POSIX file "/Users/palmglow/Documents/googledrive/orders/IFTTT/test/"
set latestFile to last item of (sort (get files of (POSIX file "/Users/palmglow/Documents/googledrive/orders/IFTTT/test")) by creation date) as alias
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFolder to "/Users/palmglow/Documents/googledrive/orders/IFTTT/test"
tell application "Finder" to set latestFile to item 1 of (sort files of (POSIX file myFolder as alias) by creation date) as alias
```

Comment: You're welcome. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: You did not include a Finder tell and did not reference the folder correctly.